# How to use matchPatch with dynamic links on React Router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The path I'm trying to match is `/threats/live/:id`

We have a component where we usually render our `breadcrumbs` in and this was how they were built using `react router v5`:

```js
const breadcrumbOptions = routes
  .filter((route) => matchPath(pathname, { path: route.link, exact: false }))
  .map((route) => ({
    ...route,
    label: route.breadCrumbtitle,
    onclick: undefined,
}))
```

For `v6` this doesn't seem to work because it looks for `:id` in the `url` but instead finds the actual `id`.

I've tried the following but it still didn't work for me

```js
const breadcrumbOptions = routes
  .filter((route) =>
    matchPath(
      { path: pathname, caseSensitive: false, end: false },
      route.link
    )
  )
  .map((route) => ({
    ...route,
    label: route.breadcrumbTitle,
    onclick: undefined,
}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in v6 the function parameters of `matchPath` were reversed.

Could you try to do

```
matchPath(route.link, pathname)
```

instead?

Comment: This seemed to work  Adding on top of this, I'm able to do a shallow comparison by doing `matchPath({ path: route.link, end: false }, pathname)`